# Effective way to merge two arrays by id, without duplication

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, duplicates

I have these arrays:

```
var first = [
    {id: 10, other: '10 - dolor'},
    {id: 12, other: '12 - sit'},
    {id: 54, other: '54 - from first'}
];

var second = [
    {id: 2, other: '2 - lorem'},
    {id: 54, other: '54 - from second'},
    {id: 80, other: '80 - ipsum'}
];
```

How could I merge them by id, without duplication? If there is duplication, no need to merge that line. I tried with [LoDash](http://lodash.com/docs), but I couldn't find the solution.

I would like to get this result:

```
var first = [
    {id: 10, other: '10 - dolor'},
    {id: 12, other: '12 - sit'},
    {id: 54, other: '54 - from first'},
    {id: 2, other: '2 - lorem'},
    {id: 80, other: '80 - ipsum'}
];
```

I need an effective solution, because there will be a huge source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the performance of it, but you could store the ids in array and if the array doesn't contain the id, the current object is pushed into the `first` array:

```
var ids = first.map(function (e) {
    return e.id;
});

var l = second.length;
for ( var i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
    if (ids.indexOf(second[i].id) === -1) {
        first.push(second[i]);
        ids.push(second[i].id);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thwny1at/

edit: EcmaScript5's `Array.prototype.map` is not supported in the older browsers, for supporting those browsers you can either use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill) or replace the `map` call with a simple `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you! It is a good solution too, but with LoDash (or underscore) it is more effective.

Comment: @kree You are welcome, sorry, but what makes you think that using `lodash` or `underscore` is more efficient that using native methods? If performance is the key, you can always test the code, http://jsperf.com/

Comment: You right, a test would be an answer. Later I will try it!

Comment: @aleha That's not completely true. That's true if we only had IE as a browser. For the _IE_ case, yes, `Array.prototype.map` can be shimmed for ES3-based browsers, if that's not an option, the `map` part can be replaced with a simple `for` loop. That's a good call, thanks, but generally, I as _one_, doesn't care about IE8 and below and other stone-aged browsers(of course not for _specific_ cases).

Answer (score 1):

here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hLtk8hq1/1/)
it using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#collections) methods.

```
_(second).each(function(si){ 
    if(!_(first).any(function(fi){ return fi.id == si.id }))
    {
        first.push(si);
    }
});
```

Comment: @kree yes, just tested in provided fiddle by changing framework to lodash

Comment: Yes, I did the same, it's works, fine! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try jquery [externd](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/):

```
var arr1 = [ 1 ,2 ,3 ];
var arr2 = [ 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ];
var k = new Array();

$.extend(k,arr1,arr2);
```

result:
k
[1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: But the id is the base of the comparison, not the whole object.